# Changing question game tag error after answers towards original tag?

Tags: discussion

I just noticed that there is a question about cross-platform play of Civilization between Xbox and PC.  It can be found here:

[**Are the Xbox and computer versions of Civilization: Revolution compatible?**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/160595/37419)

The original question asks whether or not Civ 5 can be played between PC and Xbox.  The main answer says that there is no Civ 5 for the Xbox, but then expands on the topic by talking about the Civ game that **is** available on Xbox, Civilization: Revolutions.

The answerer also discusses that either way, there is little chance that the games can be played together even if both players are playing Civ: Rev or Civ 5 between PC and Xbox.

The Questioner made a mistake and meant to say Civ: Rev and edited the question a day later after the answer had already gathered steam.  Through context clues, you can understand what has happened.

Consider, what if the question had been something much less construable like:

`"Can players play Final Fantasy XI across Xbox and PS3?"`

However, the questioner *meant* to say:

`"Can players play Final Fantasy XIV across Xbox and PS3?"`

The answer to the original question is **yes** since there was a PC/360/PS3 version of FFXI.  However, after realizing the mistake and changing the question to XIV, the answer is now **no** since there is not 360 version of XIV.

I feel like the correct way to deal with this situation is to revert the question and if the questioner still needs additional answers, create a new question.  Is this the right response?

Comment: It's rarely (if ever) appropriate to revert edits made by an asker. And I also don't feel that askers should have to ask a new question when they make a mistake (otherwise, why would the edit function exist at all?).

Comment: alerting the person who made an answer pre-edit might be a good idea though, so they can update their answer, or remove it if they don't know the ansdwer to the modified question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's a mistake or a misunderstanding in a question that causes issues with answers, generally my preferred course of action (and what happened in this case) is to leave a comment on the answer saying the question has been updated.

In these cases, I don't really see the need to ask a whole new question.

In fact, this is the way putting questions "on hold" works, in the ideal case.  The question is off-topic or unclear, and it is (hopefully) edited to make it more on-topic or add detail.  If an answer exists before the hold occurs, and the question is then edited, the answer may need editing (or in extreme cases, deletion).